# Non-kinky siphon hose?

Tags: siphon

Recently I replaced my cloudy old 1/2" i.d. siphon hose with one that gives a better view of what I'm siphoning.

The trouble is, this new hose is far more kink-prone than the old one, to the point where even moderate bends can forms kinks that stop the flow. Supply catalogues never tell you how kinky a hose is, so I'm hoping someone can point me to a sturdy, relatively kink-free solution.

Going down a size would solve the problem, all right, but I routinely siphon 24  gallons at a time. I don't want to be standing there forever waiting for kegs or carboys to fill.

Any advice or links would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the hose made of?   My silicon food grade tubing does the same thing, then i switched to something else.

Comment: It's food grade PVC. The old one was food grade vinyl and a lot less kinky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I recently picked up some 1/2" Versa Fittings FDA Grade PVC hose, made in Canada, and it's superior in every way to the stuff that was driving me nuts (which is likewise food-grade PVC and likewise made in Canada).

Just thought I'd pass on the info in case anyone else is looking for relatively kink-free siphon hose.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a spring over the bend and maintain visibility of that section of hose, or use a small section of a harder hose (such as garden hose) if visibility isn't important. If the garden hose diameter is too small you can slit it, or visit a gas station's dumpster (or ask) for a small section of radiator hose.

[image: Radiator Hose]

[image: Add a spring to prevent the hose from kinking]

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a racking cane with a more complete bend on it, so that the hose doesn't have to bend as much?

Comment: My racking cane has a 'U' bend at the top. This hose is so darn limp that any bend eventually causes a flow-reducing kink. Guess I'll just order a couple of hoses from different suppliers, and hope to find one that isn't a wet noodle.

Comment: Sounds like the hose is too long then? Or you're trying to take it over a large distance. Do you just put the carboy on a bench, and the keg immediately below it?

Comment: Hose length is the same as the old one (about 6'), and in any case length wouldn't make a difference. Height of head would, but my 3-foot high brewing bench hasn't gotten any taller. It has to be either the wall thickness or, more likely, the material. Time to go hose shopping.

Comment: My point is, why not just use a hose that's the right length? The only change of direction that you *must* have is to get over the neck of the carboy, after that, it should be a straight line down. If the line from the end of your cane to the mouth of the keg is straight and your hose is still kinking, then your hose is too long. I've never seen a straight hose develop a kink of its own accord.